# How to effectively create duplicate rows in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to transfer my pandas code into polars but I have a difficulties with duplicating lines (I need it for my pyvista visualizations).
In pandas I did the following:

```
data['key'] = data['key'].apply(lambda x: 2*[x])
data = data.explode('key', 
            ignore_index=False
         )
```

In polars LazyFrame I tried

```
data.with_columns(
    (pl.col("key").apply(lambda x: [x]*2))
    .explode()
    )
data.select(pl.col("key")).collect()
```

but it raises:

```
ShapeError: unable to add a column of length 2000 to a dataframe of height 1000
```

I also tried to avoid apply using

```
data.with_columns(
    (pl.col("key").cast(pl.List(float))*2)
    .explode()
    )
```

but it only raises:

```
PanicException: `mul` operation not supported for dtype `list[f64]`
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you show an actual before/after example? e.g. `data = pl.DataFrame(dict(key=[1, 2, 3]))`

Comment: you can reproduce is with: 
import polars as pl;
data = pl.LazyFrame(
    {
        "key": [1,5,18,32.56,18,65]
    }
    )
and adding data = in front of every operation. print(data.collect())will raise the error

Comment: Yes, thank you. But if you put that information in your actual example/question - it makes it much easier for everybody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.repeat_by()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html#polars.Expr.repeat_by) and [`.flatten()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.flatten.html#polars.Expr.flatten)

`.apply()` (now named `.map_elements()`) should "never" be used in Polars.

> **Warning:** This method is much slower than the native expressions API. Only use it if you cannot implement your logic otherwise.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({ "key": [1, 2, 3], "value": [4, 5, 6] })

df.select(pl.all().repeat_by(2).flatten())
```

```py
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ key ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4     │
│ 1   ┆ 4     │
│ 2   ┆ 5     │
│ 2   ┆ 5     │
│ 3   ┆ 6     │
│ 3   ┆ 6     │
└─────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for anybody struggling with using `repeat_by(n)` on a dataframe with list columns, as I was, here is a solution:

```
a = pl.DataFrame({
     "foo": [1,5,2,],
     "bar": [[2,5],[6,3],[1,2,5]]
     })

r = a.with_columns(
        pl.col("foo").repeat_by(2)
    ).explode("foo")
```

result:

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar       │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [2, 5]    │
│ 1   ┆ [2, 5]    │
│ 5   ┆ [6, 3]    │
│ 5   ┆ [6, 3]    │
│ 2   ┆ [1, 2, 5] │
│ 2   ┆ [1, 2, 5] │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [polars.LazyFrame.explode()](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.explode.html#polars.LazyFrame.explode):

```
import polars as pl

data = pl.LazyFrame({"key": [1, 5, 18, 32.56, 18, 65]})
data = data.with_columns((pl.col("key").apply(lambda x: [x] * 2))).explode("key")
print(data.select(pl.col("key")).collect())
```

Comment: You should use [`repeat_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html#polars.Expr.repeat_by) instead of apply: `pl.col("key").repeat_by(2)` (apply should "never" be used)

Comment: @jqurious make it an answer and maybe OP will reselect the proper way to do it.